# Multiple views on top of an ImageView

Tags: android

I'm trying to port an app from iOS to Android. In my iOS app I have an image view which displays a map, and on top of it I want to display multiple button views on certain specific positions.

None of the standard views in Android seem to fit my needs, but I am surely missing something. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with setting your image as the background for a RelativeLayout - and then putting the buttons in whichever way you want to arrange them?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just that new to Android and that stupid not to realize that, thank you, please post your reply as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to use any layout that's best suited for your needs (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) and set its background to any image you need.  I believe the image will automatically scale to fill the corresponding Layout.  Put the image into the appropriate `drawable` folders - and format your XML similar to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/buttons"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_image">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```